# MS-Access updating first record when adding record

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm fairly new to access but not to vba. I have a form that inserts data to a table with vba

```
rcrdAdd = "INSERT INTO " & timeTbl & " (ProjectNumber, AssignedTo, Task, taskStart) VALUES ('" & ProjectNumber.Value & "', '" & combobox.value & "', '" & combobox.value & "', '" & datetime.value & "');"
    db.Execute rcrdAdd, dbFailOnError
```

When i run this it does add the record but it also updates the first record in the table with the project number associated with record it just added.

I don't know what or why. Can anyone shed any light here. I have tried to research why and can not find an answer

Comment: In the code  you wrote before, `rcrdAdd` is only doing "INSERT INTO". You should check all your code, clean your execute statement or maybe is a thrigger in SQL which start at INSERT in this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is bound to a the table's recordsource and it looks like you've created a project number text box that is bound to the field

Then it looks like you're typing in the new project number (`ProjectNumber.Value`) for the Insert.

That will automatically update the current record when you leave - most likely you're opening the form to the first record in the table

Just create a new TEXTBOX that is  UNBOUND - and use that in your `INSERT INTO` SQL instead of `ProjectNumber.Value`

Comment: thank you dbmitch I don't know why I couldn't see this probably looking at it too long.

Comment: No problem - sometimes a second set of eyes helps